# Trying to get character count frequency in C using argv?

Tags: c

I am trying to produce something like this:

INPUT:

./program aaabbbsssddd

OUTPUT:

a3b3s3d3

So far, I have code that looks like this, but for some reason I am only pulling the first letters, when I want to be pulling every letter and then testing against its frequency.... I am new to C, so any suggestions would be great:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
        int x;

        if (argc < 2) {
                printf("error\n");
                return 0;
        }

        for (x = 1; x < argc; x++) {
                printf("%c",argv[x][0]);
        }
        printf("\n");

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: `argc` is not a length of the parameter string, but the number of parameters. You have one.

Comment: `argv[x][0]` this is only going to get you the first character. You need to turn it around `argv[1][x]` and have `x` start on 0 until `strlen(argv[1])`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that @RickAstley

Comment: `argv[x][0]` is saying "give me the first character of the x'th string in `argv`". Which is `a` in the case of `./program aaabbbsssddd` and `x` 1.

Comment: Ignore the `argv` for the moment. Can you solve `char *str = "aaabbbsssddd";` first? If you can do that, doing the same some argument read from cmdline is straightforward.

Answer (score 3):

`argv` is an array of C strings; `argc` indicates how many string parameters have been passed, not the length of the string.

Since you are passing a single parameter to your program, all you need is `argv[1]` string. Use a pointer to go through its characters, stopping when you reach null character:

```
if (argc != 2) {
    printf("error: pass one parameter.\n");
    return -1;
}
char *ptr = argv[1];
int count[1u + CHAR_MAX - CHAR_MIN] = {0};
while (*ptr) {
    count[(unsigned char)*ptr]++;
    ptr++;
}
```

Now `count[i]` contains the number the character with code `i` occurs in the parameter passed to your program. You can print the counts as follows:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i != 256 ; i++) {
    if (count[i]) {
        printf("'%c' : %d\n", i, count[i]);
    }
}
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/sDDEnE)

Comment: Question... I have changed the code to look like this: `printf("%c%d", i, count[i]);`... is there a way to test whether or not this outputted string is longer than the original string?

Comment: @sgerbhctim `printf` returns character count. Store it in a variable, and compare it to `strlen(argv[1])`

Comment: What do you mean `printf` returns character count?

Comment: @sgerbhctim Declare `int total = 0;` before the loop, and do `total += printf("%c%d", i, count[i]);` inside the loop. At the end of the loop `total` will hold the number of characters printed.

Comment: `256` is OK, yet is a [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)).  An alternative might include `256` --> `[1u + CHAR_MAX - CHAR_MIN]`.

Comment: Perhaps `count[*ptr - CHAR_MIN]++;`? and adjustments to the `for()` code too.  Still nice answer.  I just like to avoid casts when practical.

Answer (score 1):

argc is the number of arguments you pass to the program.

So , argc is 2 in the above case which is "aaabbbsssddd" ,
which is stored in argv[1] 
as argv[0] is the name of the program.

So, Modify the code according to that ,by taking the length of the argument passed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
        int x;

        if (argc < 2) {
                printf("error\n");
                return 0;
        }   

        // take a count array to maintain the counts of each character
        // set initially to zero
        int count[256] = {0};
        int len = strlen(argv[1]);
        for (x = 0; x < len; x++) 
        {   
            char c = argv[1][x];
            // Increment character count 
            count[c]++;
            //printf("%c",argv[1][x]);
        }   
        int i;
        int outputLen = 0;
        for(i=0; i < 256; i++)
        {   
            // If count is greater than zero, then print it 
            if(count[i])
            {
               // add the length of the output
                outputLen += printf("%c%d",i,count[i]);
            }
        }   

        printf("\n");

        // Here you have both input and output length 
        if(len  > outputLen)
        {
        }


        return 0;

}
```

Comment: Checking the length of `argv[1]` every iteration of the loop isn't very efficient - better to check for a NUL character.

Comment: any chance you can help me modify this for my case?

Comment: Right now, you are just printing the argument as such by reading it character by character. I did the same also by modifying as little as I can. Do you want the complete solution for your question ?